# is never assigned to, and will always have its default value

Tags: c#

Im trying to select a name from a dropdown list created from a database. I cant seem to get the mane to assign.

When I click the select button it does not carry the persons name in the comboBox1 through to me next lot of code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace GlidingLogsGUI2
{
public partial class InstructorSelectionForm : Form
{
    List<Person> instructors = new List<Person>();
    Person selectedPerson;

    public InstructorSelectionForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TopMost = true;

        List<Person> instructors = new List<Person>();
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Personnel WHERE [Current?] = TRUE AND [Position] = ?", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", PositionIDs.INSTRUCTOR));

        OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                instructors.Add(new Person(dr));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        foreach (Person a in instructors)
        comboBox1.Items.Add(a.FirstName + " " + a.Surname);
    }

    private void Selectbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedPerson == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A person must be selected first");
            return;
        }

        new F5363(selectedPerson);
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }

    private void InstructorSelectForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? There seems to be the end of a warning/error/exception in the title, but I can't guess.

Comment: The problem is that the selected person is null? Declare it please..

Comment: Just **never** use empty catch clauses.

Comment: How can i declaer selectedPerson, i have tried a few ways but ether get more errors or still not declared.

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring selectedPerson, but never setting it anywhere. I suspect what you want to do is to remove the current declaration of selectedPerson and change the click event to something similar to;

```
private void Selectbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    Person selectedPerson = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Person;
    if (selectedPerson == null)
    {
...
```

Comment: I have found my fault. i was creasting a list of instructors twice.  List<Person> instructors = new List<Person>();